# How to sort set into exclusive pairs?

Tags: combinatorics

This came up in a real life situation and we were trying to find the way to both express this formally and then solve for if it is possible or not.

We have 2 teams of 4 players each. Team $X$ $(A,B,C,D)$ and Team $Y$ $(1,2,3,4)$.

We would like to do a tournament with $4$ different types of games and $4$ rounds (so each person can play each game, example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DnDnDyOvh8P8HDhua5TSnGpwaxrsuciOuKGBiu-KvME/edit?usp=sharing)

Is it possible for Team $X$ to play Team $Y$ without repeating the following

*Game Type

*Opponent

*Round (cause the player can only play 1 game per round).

Again, more so than the specifics of my example we are looking for how to solve similar situations in the future.

-Abhi

Comment: Are you using $A$ and $B$ to denote both teams and players?

Comment: Yes I was, edited Teams A an B to Teams X and Y for clarity.

Comment: I think this is possible. It could be that you need to model this in the form of a circular matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix (See first line)

Comment: Thanks Ploni, Again, more than the explicit solution I wanted to know what domain this type of problem falls into. Should I mark this as answered?